# Does Mathematica has a notion of Half Year in its DateObject

Tags: date-and-time

I can convert any `DateObject` to its current quarter as follows:

```
DateObject[Now,"Quarter"]
```

But if I want to look at whether my datetime stamp is in the first half or the second half of the year, what is the key for that?

```
DateObject[Now,"YearHalf"]
```

Comment: The documentation of [`DateObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject.html) lists the granularities available. There does not seem to be a built-in intermediate step between "Year" and "Quarter".

Comment: Is there a mechanism to create your own granularity?

Comment: How are you intending to use these `"YearHalf"` DateObjects?

Comment: @Edmund I have one of the date fields acting inside a `GroupBy`. So I needed different granularity to produce different summary statistics. The keyword `"YearHalf"` was just my guess (I am not using it). But now since there is no way to have such granularity I have to resort to converting `DateObjects` to `Strings` to achieve what I want which is very inefficient since I have very a large dataset. I do think mathematica should provide a way to create custom granularity to keep the code nice and clean.

Answer (score 2):

Since you only need the `"YearHalf"` concept for grouping you may introduce a [`DayRound`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DayRound.html) granularity using a `yearHalf` symbol with [`TagSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html).

```
yearHalf /:
 DayRound[d_, yearHalf] :=
 DateObject[{
   DateValue[d, "Year"],
   6 UnitStep[DateValue[d, "Month"] - 7] + 1,
   1
   }]
```

`yearHalf` now works with `DayRound` to make it return 1 January for the first half of the year and 1 July for the second half of the year.

```
DayRound[#, yearHalf] & /@ DateObject /@ {{2019, 2, 1}, {2019, 9, 30}}
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

With a few `dates`.

```
dates = DateRange[DateObject@{2019, 1, 1}, DateObject@{2020, 6, 1}, "Month"];
```

Then `DayRound` can be used in [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) to collect the dates by `yearHalf`.

```
GroupBy[DayRound[#, yearHalf] &]@dates
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.